# Error with hardware virtualization kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I'm noob, and I try to install linux and when I want to start I have invalid settings detected(hardware virtualization), But when I want to disable in system / acceleration but the button doesn't activate. And I want to know what I can do for resolve this error. I have Windows 10 and it's kali linux in oracle VM VirtualBox. If someone have solution it's cool if can help me

---

i have this and ok no active :/ 
[image]

---

and this is the error but dont understand what problem. And need to go BIOS?

[image]

Comment: if you are a linux noob, then you should not be installing kali .... try a more friendly distribution, such as Mint
 https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361

Comment: Use snipping tool to make better images ( The text is blurred, and unreadable ).

Comment: Leaving aside the potential difficulties of working with Kali, the most likely problem is exactly as @user703702 suggested, namely that one must enable virtualization in the BIOS. You did not specify what machine you have, but see [Enabling Virtualization](https://bce.berkeley.edu/enabling-virtualization-in-your-pc-bios.html) or [CPU Virtualization in Computer BIOS](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-cpu-virtualization-in-your-computer-bios/).

Answer (score 1):

You see this error?
[image: Virtualisation Error box]

In affirmative case, you need to access your BIOS and enable virtualization technology.
In negative case, can you send us an image of the error?